# Search in a field with html entities

Tags: html, t-sql, entities

Our customer's data (SQL Server 2005) has html entities in it (é -> &eacute;).

We need to search inside those fields, so a search for "équipe" will find "&eacute;quipe".

We can't change the data, because our customer's customers can edit those fields as will (with a HTML editor), so if we remove the entities, on the next edit they might reappear, and the problem will still be there.
We can't use a .net server-side function, because we need to find the rows before they are returned to the server.

I would use a function that replaces the entities by their UTF-8 counterparts, but it's kind of tiresome, and I think it seriously drops the search performances (something about full table scan if I recall correctly).

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would only need to examine and encode the incoming search term.
If you convert "`équipe`" to "`&eacute;quipe`" and use that in your WHERE/FTS clause then any index on that field could still be used, if the optimizer deems it appropriate.

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I didn't think of that.